# No response on calling php function from javascript file

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I think this will be a really simple question, but as I'm not a web developer, i'm getting stucked and without direction.

As the title question says, i need call a php function from my JS file. The method i'm doing this is using jquery with ajax (after the research tells me to do so), but when i'm calling my separate php file that I create with the things that i want to do, it never appears to actually executing the .php.

On my JS file, I have this:

```
function check_empty() {
if (document.getElementById('name').value == "" || document.getElementById('email').value == "" || document.getElementById('msg').value == "") {
    alert("Por favor, preencher todos os campos");
} else {
    var request = $.ajax({
      url: "sendmail.php",
      method: "POST",
      data: { name : document.getElementById('name').value,
              email : document.getElementById('email').value, 
              msg : document.getElementById('msg').value },
              //dataType: "html"
    });

    request.done(function( msg ) {
      alert("Email enviado com sucesso...");
    });

    request.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
      alert( "Falha no envio do email: " + textStatus );
    });
    document.getElementById('abc').style.display = "none";
}
return false;
}
```

And in my php file i have the following:

```
<?php 
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Username = '*******@gmail.com';
$mail->Password = '********';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'SSL';
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->From = '********@gmail.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Marcelo Porto';
$mail->addReplyTo('********@gmail.com','Reply Adress');
$mail->addAddress($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);
$mail->Subject = 'Interesse por Obra';
$mail->Body = $_POST['msg'];
$mail->send();
?>
```

I'm appending jquery on my main html file with:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

My main html summarized, with the check_empty() function call on Button:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Acervo</title>
<link href="./stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js_proj.js"></script>
</head>
<body id="body" bgcolor="#B4B4B4">
<div style= "display:none;" class="popupSheet" id="abc" >
<!-- Popup Div Starts Here -->
<div class="popupSheet" id="popupContact" >
<!-- Contact Us Form -->
<form class="popupSheet" id="form" name="form">
<img class="popupSheet" id="close" src="images/4.svg" onclick ="div_hide()">
<h2 class="popupSheet" >Entre em contato</h2>
<hr class="popupSheet">
<input class="popupSheet" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Nome" type="text">
<input class="popupSheet" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="text">
<textarea class="popupSheet" id="msg" name="message" placeholder="Mensagem"></textarea>
<button type="button" class="popupSheet" onClick = "check_empty()" id="submit">Enviar</a>
</form>
</div>
<!-- Popup Div Ends Here -->
</div>
```

I have alredy tried a number of changes on the structure, so I thinking i'm missing something very specific. Debbug leaves no clue of what is happening, or i'm not understanding...

[image]

I really appreciate any help.

Currently, I'm running this on my localhost, and all the mentioned files are placed in the very same folder.

Comment: Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?

Comment: Welcome to SO. And thank you for a well thought out post. It shows some research and we look forward to helping you find your answer. Can we see the HTML too. I do not see how your ajax call is being triggered.

Comment: `url: "sendmail.php",` this will send HTTP POST request to **yourdomain.com/sendmail.php** are you sure that this is the right place of your script? Also could you check in developer console(most of major browsers have one) in network tab when you submit the ajax request what is the status code returned

Comment: something I try to make sure that my php page is getting hit is to simply `var_dump($_POST);` so you will see some output in your network tab of your document inspector

Comment: Thanks for the network tip on debugging, Codtex. When all finishes, i receive as response the following: Invalid address:  (addAnAddress to): email

Being email my second parameter on ajax data.

I'll try this method, happymacarts.

Comment: you have a "reply to" but you did not specify a "TO" address and the "reply a[d]dress" has a typo but should not be causing issue